# The order of $G$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Q}$, and so we have that $H^n(G,\mathbb{Q})=0$ for $n≥1$, why is so?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

**Group Cohomology:** Question $2$

I am learning group cohomology. In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology), I need to understand the section $\text{Higher cohomology groups are torsion}$.

The discussion says the cohomology groups $H^n(G,M)$ for finite groups $G$ are all torsion group. This is clear to me.

But it says that the short exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to 0$ yields an isomorphism $$\text{Hom}(G, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})=H^1(G, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \cong H^2(G, \mathbb{Z})  $$ where $G$ acts trivially on each groups in the short exact sequence.

I understand from a previous discussion that if $G$ acts trivially on $M$, then $\text{Hom}(G, M)=H^1(G, M) $.

> But I didn't understand why $H^1(G, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \cong H^2(G, \mathbb{Z})$ ?

An explanation is given in the following para in the above section:

$\text{If the order of G is invertible in a $G$-module $M$ (for example, if $M$ is a $ \mathbb {Q}$ -vector space),}$ $\text{the transfer map can be used to show that $H^{n}(G,M)=0$ for $n ⩾ 1$}$. $\text{A typical application of this fact is as follows: the long exact cohomology sequence}$ $\text{ of the short exact sequence (where all three groups have a trivial $G$-action) }$

So according to the above suggestion we have the long exact cohomology sequence $$0 \to \mathbb{Z}^G \to \mathbb{Q}^G \to (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})^G \xrightarrow{\delta_0} H^1(G,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(G,\mathbb{Q}) \to H^1(G, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \xrightarrow{\delta_1} H^2(G, \mathbb{Z}) \to \cdots $$

We have to show $\delta_1$ is an isomorphism.

**Edit:** The order of $G$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Q}$, and so we have that $H^n(G,\mathbb{Q})=0$ for $n≥1$, why is so ?

Any help please

Comment: Since the order of $G$ is invertible in $\mathbb Q$, you have that $H^n(G, \mathbb Q) = 0$ for $n \geq 1$. Hence $H^1(G, \mathbb Q) = H^2(G, \mathbb Q) = 0$, thus in the long exact cohomology sequence you have $\cdots \to H^1(G, \mathbb Q) \to H^1(G, \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z) \rightarrow^{\delta_1} H^2(G, \mathbb Z) \to H^2(G, \mathbb Q) \to \cdots $, i.e. $\cdots \to 0 \to H^1(G, \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z) \rightarrow^{\delta_1} H^2(G, \mathbb Z) \to 0 \to \cdots$,. What can you now say about the kernel and image of $\delta_1$?

Comment: @Rushy, I understand but how the order of $G$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Q}$ implies $H^n(G,\mathbb{Q})=0$ ?

Comment: @Why You have a module that is both torsion and in which an element acts invertibly. :)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, Sorry, I didn't get it. For example, if $G=\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Q}$, then there is only the $zero$-homomorphism from $G$ to $M$ if we view $\mathbb{Q}$ as an additive group.  Can you please elaborate your comment ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a direct consequence of Maschke's theorem (In fact, it is equivalent to it) : if the order of the characteristic of the field $\mathbb k$ does not divide the order of the group $G$, then every $\mathbb k G$-module is projective (that is, every short exact sequence of modules splits). This means that projective resolutions have length $0$, and that there is no cohomology (in fact, $H^n(G, V)$ vanishes for every representation $V$ and every $n \geq 1$).

Comment: Excellent answer. It solved my all doubts.

Comment: You're welcome !

Comment: @J.Darné Sorry for such a late comment. You have proved that every $kG$-module is projective, where $k = \mathbb{Q}$ according to what OP wants. Yet to show $H^n(G,V)=0$, we need $V$ to be a projective $\mathbb{Z}G$-module, so it seems that an extra step of "restriction of scalar" $$U: \mathbb{Q}G-\mathsf{Mod} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}G-\mathsf{Mod}$$ needs to be taken, and we need $U$ to send projective objects to projective objects. However, I got stuck here. To show this, I need that $\mathbb{Q}G-\mathsf{Mod}$ is projective as a $\mathbb{Z}G-\mathsf{Mod}$, yet I don't know how to show this.

Comment: @HetongXu You seem to be confused about the definition of $H^n(G,V)$. $H^*(G,V) = Ext^*(k, V)$ is computed in the category of $kG$-modules. If you change k, the cohomology can of course change. All I was saying was that if the order of $G$ is invertible in $k$ (a fixed field), then the cohomology vanishes. Which I true for $k= \mathbb Q$, but not if $k = \mathbb Z$. I did not say anything about the cohomology of a $\mathbb Q G$-module seen as a $\mathbb Z G$-module.

Comment: @J.Darné Thank you for your help! The definition that I have learnt on the cohomology of groups is that $H^n(G,A) := \mathrm{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}G}^n(\mathbb{Z},A)$, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is regarded as a trivial $\mathbb{Z}G$-module and $A$ is any $\mathbb{Z}G$-module. (As defined in both Weibel's and Rotman's book on homological algebra) So it seems that it is a matter of different definitions. Thank you for your help! :)